# how to download a file using gsutil

Tags: powershell

I'm starting to use gsutil on windows xp.I have Python 2.7 in c:\Python27.  I have setup and can run Python scripts including gsutil in my Windows PowerShell ide succesfully to list my files. EG gsutil ls -L gs://mybucket shows my files present and correct. The developers guide suggests the following example to download a file from storage

```
    gsutil cp gs://cats/*.jpg file://pets/
```

I dont understand the syntax here. I have a file in storage gs://pussy/debug.txt and I want to download it to c:\test\debug.txt
How should I write this command.
I tried

```
     gsutil cp gs://pussy/debug.txt file c:\test\
```

but it gives me the following error

```
    At line:1 char:7
    + gsutil <<<<  cp gs://pussy/debug.txt file c:\test\
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Copying gs://pussy/debug.txt...:S 
    tring) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\gsutil\gsutil.py", line 88, in <module>
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 199, in main
    parallel_operations)
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 287, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExc
    eptions
    parallel_operations)
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 188, in RunNamedCommand
    return command_inst.RunCommand()
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\commands\cp.py", line 2273, in RunCommand
    shared_attrs)
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command.py", line 803, in Apply
    use_thr_exc_handler=ignore_subprocess_failures)
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\command.py", line 908, in _ApplyThreads
    return_value = func(args)
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\commands\cp.py", line 2143, in _CopyFunc
    self._PerformCopy(exp_src_uri, dst_uri))
    File "c:\gsutil\gslib\commands\cp.py", line 1560, in _PerformCopy
    src_key = src_uri.get_key(False, download_headers)
    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\storage_uri.py", line 189, in get_key
    key = bucket.get_key(self.object_name, headers, version_id)
    File "c:\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\file\bucket.py", line 92, in get_key
    fp = open(key_name, 'rb')
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'file'
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

The first command is assuming unix paths. You'll need to do the following to use it on windows:

```
gsutil cp gs://folder/filename c:\destfolder\file
```

OR

```
gsutil cp gs://folder/filename file:///c|/destfolder/file
```

Or possibly even

```
gsutil cp 'gs://folder/filename' 'file:///c|/destfolder/file'
```

Or with variables

```
$src = 'gs://folder/filename';
$dest = 'file:///c:/destfolder/file'
gsutil cp $src $dest
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue.

They way I make it work is simple, do not include ":" they are not allow on this type of path.

For example try something like this:

python gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/reviews/reviews_com.YYYYY.ZZZZ_201501.csv 'test/'

It will create a folder called test and save the file inside

Hope it helps.